# How many people did Walter White kill or cause to be killed?

Tags: breaking-bad

By the end of season 5, Walter White has racked up quite the kill count.

How many people did he kill directly?

How many people were killed because of his actions?

Answer (score 6):

### Directly/in-directly, at least 199

### Total meth users, and any related deaths: Incalculable

The Radio Times has totalled up [Every person Walter White murdered in Breaking Bad](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/2015-10-15/every-person-walter-white-murdered-in-breaking-bad/)

I won't list every entry here, but here are a few samples:

> Emilio Koyama
>
> Who: Drug dealer
>
> How: Under the guise of teaching the dealer his meth recipe, Walt created deadly phosphene gas and trapped Emilio in the RV to asphyxiate.
>
> Why: Tried to rip off Walt and Jesse on their very first deal, was almost certainly going to kill them.
>
> Justification: Self-defence
>
> **Total: 1**

---

> Krazy 8
>
> Who: Drug dealer
>
> How: Choked with a bike lock.
>
> Why: Krazy 8 survived the phosphene gas, leading Walt and Jesse to keep him locked up in the basement. While Walt formed a connection with Krazy, he realised that the gangster was planning on stabbing him with a piece of broken plate.
>
> Justification: Self-defence-ish
>
> **Total: 2**

---

> 167 passengers and one air traffic controller
>
> Who: Every passenger on two aeroplanes that collided over ABQ, the air traffic controller responsible, plus one pink teddy bear.
>
> How: Bear with me. Walt let Jane Margolis died. Her father Donald, an air traffic controller, was so wracked with grief he couldn’t concentrate on his job and made a fatal error. He later killed himself out of guilt.
>
> Why: The effects of Walt’s action ripple out and corrupt everything.
>
> Justification: Chaos theory.
>
> **Total: 171**

### **The list goes on.**

Many more victims are identified, but the total number is hard to guess. This is because we don't know how many people used his product:

> Meth users and the wider populace
>
> Who: The hopeless addicts who use Walt’s products, and everyone else his selfish quest has destroyed.
>
> How: Andrea and the crashed planes show how Walt has spread like a cancer through Albuquerque and beyond. How many people have died using, selling and fighting over his product, or through unforeseen consequences of his actions? We can’t know. In many ways, Walt is directly responsible for almost every death in the series. As in chemistry, he was the catalyst. The reaction is now out of control.
>
> Why: Walter White.
>
> Justification: Walter White.
>
> **Total: Incalculable**

Comment: Well, you could at least list the deaths related to the Gus Fring / Jack Welker gangs...

Comment: @RingØ Please feel free to amend the answer with any additional information. I’m only presenting what the source provided.

Comment: Dead link :( :(